# Can't lock Spotify to launcher

Tags: spotify

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 and to Spotify 0.9.10, I can no longer lock the Spotify icon to the launcher. The option is still there, but clicking "Lock to launcher" does nothing, and subsequent right clicks show that the option is still "Lock to launcher" instead of "Unlock from launcher".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would try removing Spotify from the launcher and re-adding it. Alternately, you can make a `Spotify.desktop` file with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/spotify
Name=Spotify
Icon=/opt/spotify/spotify-client/Icons/spotify-linux-512.png
```

You should be able to drag this file directly to the launcher from the file browser.

Comment: This procedure creates the [Duplicate (Spotify) Icon in launcher](http://askubuntu.com/q/343092/177437) issue.