# How to add running program icon to left-side bar?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, unity, command-line, bash

As in question, how can we assign an icon here?

[image]

Regards

Comment: which program is that? usually it is a program specific bug like - http://askubuntu.com/questions/40380/how-to-set-an-icon-for-eclipse , http://askubuntu.com/questions/465288/launcher-duplicate-iconless-icon , http://askubuntu.com/questions/343092/duplicate-spotify-icon-in-launcher

Answer (score 0):

That's the Launcher.

When you run a program, it's icon appears in the Launcher. If you right click on the icon in the launcher, you can select to lock it to the Launcher so you can run it quickly in future.

If you have lots of them in the Launcher, you can resize the Launcher icons as required by selecting `Appearance` in `System Settings`and moving the slider as required.

[image]

Comment: I dont mean quick launch icon but the one which is responsible for current window. This icon has question mark in this bar but in "Search your computer and online sources"(under windows hotkey) it has its normal graphic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drag and drop an icon from the dash into the lancher.

Comment: I dont want. When I drag it the permanent icon has the normal image. But this responsible for current window one still has question mark.

Comment: Then it's sound like a bug. The description of your problem is not good, please improve it. (We understood that you wanted to create an icon in the launcher, not that you already have an icon in the launcher, and when you click on it, you have a new "question mark" icon that appear for the windows just started. It is that your problem right?). Is it doing that with all application? Only Eclipse??