# Two icons on Unity Launcher on non-standard application launch

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop

I have an application which doesn't come from any Ubuntu repo (neither official, nor PPA) but available as tgz and supposed to be unpacked and ready to use. To be precise it is [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/).

The problem is the  application when launched shows its own icon in Unity Launcher. After making a custom `.desktop` file and placing shortcut onto Unity Launcher (by dragging from the dash) and launching it I see two icons - one placed by me and another one with real application.

This is the `.desktop` contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/LightTable/LightTable
Name=Light Table
Icon=/opt/LightTable/core/img/lticon.png
```

One more thing. The `/opt/LightTable/LightTable` is bash script file and eventually `/opt/LightTable/ltbin` is being launched. I think this is the problem but have no idea how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a StartupWMClass string into your .desktop file. This is a string that defines in which class the application is grouped in the Unity Launcher at startup.

The solution is to add `StartupWMClass` to your desktop file. First you need to find the proper class for your application.

It is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-represent-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file) (Thanks to [@chaos](https://askubuntu.com/users/185729/chaos)).

Open your Light Table window and type in terminal:

```
xprop WM_CLASS
```

Then click on the LIght Table window.

For gnome terminal WM_CLASS should be something like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal", "Gnome-terminal"
```

So all windows with WM_CLASS "gnome-terminal" and "Gnome-terminal" are grouped together. For light table you will see different class. Pick one and remember it.

After you find your program class add this to your .desktop file:

```
StartupWMClass=CLASS
```

Replace CLASS with the class from previous command.

Comment: Thanks! Actually tried that previously. In my case it was `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "ltbin", "Ltbin"`. I've tried it with `StartupWMClass=Ltbin` and it didn't work, but after your answer I tried `StartupWMClass=ltbin` and worked like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: *UPD*: [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343092/duplicate-spotify-icon-in-launcher) misleaded me.